# Actionscript, Need help in loaderInfo.url for special characters

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, special-characters

I am facing a strange problem here. I have a swf-file hosted on a server whose web-path would be look like this

```
http://abc/1/Test-Fåram/img.JPG
```

but when I do a following statement inside my flash

ActionScript Code:

```
trace (this.loaderInfo.url);
```

It will output

```
http://abc/1/Test-F%E5rram/img.JPG
```

I am nearly pulling out my hair why it will adding 'AN EXTRA' r inside the url

I tried encodeURI, decodeURI, and so many things but didn't get it through.

Another interesting thing is, I have noticed that whatever I placed after 'å' It will repeat the immediate character right after it. 
for example If I change the path to

http://abc/1/Test-Fåjam/img.JPG

The output of the trace will become

```
http://abc/1/Test-F%E5jjam/img.JPG
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards

Zubair

Edit:

I have found some more info, it seems like to be a browser specific problem , the loaderInfo.url returns valid path when i run my .swf in Internet Explorer, but gives invalid results on FireFox and Chrome browsers
my flash player versions are

FireFox: 11.1.102.63
Chrome: 11.2.202.229
Internet Explorer: 11.1.102.62

And these are the latest ones till the time of posting.

Comment: trace(encodeURI("å")) gives me %C3%A5

Comment: What does it outputs with trace(encodeURI("år"))

Comment: actually you are right in your sense, but I am talking about the problem with this.loaderInfo.url, to see my problem do the following

1- Make a folder and named it "Test-Fåram".
2- Create a swf file and in its first frame write the following
trace(this.loaderInfo.url)
3- Save the swf under "Test-Fåram", and Test the movie, and see the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some more info, it seems like to be a browser specific problem , the loaderInfo.url returns valid path when i run my .swf in Internet Explorer, but gives invalid results on FireFox and Chrome browsers my flash player versions are

FireFox: 11.1.102.63 Chrome: 11.2.202.229 Internet Explorer: 11.1.102.62